# Architectural Design of Restful API Server

Tags: spring, oop, design-patterns, restful-architecture

I'm creating a Restfull API Server using Spring 3.1 / Hibernate / Jackson.

I have a '**Purchase**' Controller/Model/Dao.

I now need to add the ability to '**Tag**' a purchase.

So a simple class with a 'tagId' and 'tagName' linked back to the 'Purchase'.
A 'Purchase' can have many 'Tags', a 'Tag' can belong to only one 'Purchase'.

What is the best way to represent this new 'Tag' class I must add? I.e.

- Should I add purchaseId attribute to 'Tag' model and annonate it somehow?
- Should I add a 'Tags List' attribuate to Purchase' model?
- Would I create a 'Tag' controller that would be a subclass of 'PurchaseController'?
- Etc...

Essentially, I'm looking for the best practice way to design this using Spring.

Additionally, any suggestions on design patterns I could employ would be welcome.
Maybe the Decorator pattern is applicable here?

All Purchases and Tags must persist to a database of course.

Thanks

Purchase Controller:

```
@Controller
public class PurchaseController
{

    @Autowired
    private IPurchaseService purchaseService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "purchase", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public final List<Purchase> getAll()
    {
        return purchaseService.getAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "purchase/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public final Purchase get(@PathVariable("id") final Long id)
    {
        return RestPreconditions.checkNotNull(purchaseService.getById(id));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "purchase/tagged", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public final List<Purchase> getTagged()
    {
        return RestPreconditions.checkNotNull(purchaseService.getTagged());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "purchase/pending", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public final List<Purchase> getPending()
    {
        return RestPreconditions.checkNotNull(purchaseService.getPending());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "purchase", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void create(@RequestBody final Purchase entity)
    {
        RestPreconditions.checkRequestElementNotNull(entity);
        purchaseService.addPurchase(entity);
    }
}
```

Purchase Model:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Purchase implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6603477834338392140L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long pan;

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getPan()
    {
        return pan;
    }

    public void setPan(Long pan)
    {
        this.pan = pan;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purchase model needs to be modified like below.

```
@Entity
public class Purchase implements Serializable
{
/**
 * 
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6603477834338392140L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long pan;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instance", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    public Long getId()
    {
      return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getPan()
    {
        return pan;
    }

    public void setPan(Long pan)
    {
        this.pan = pan;
    }

    public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags){
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<Tag> getTags(){
        if(tags == null){
           tags = new LinkedHashSet<Tag>();
        }
        return tags;
    }
}
```

and Tag model will look something like below.

```
@Entity
public class Tag implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "PURCHASE__ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
    private Purchase purchase;

    //Other attributes, getters and setters

   @JsonIgnore
   public Purchase getPurchase(){
       return this.purchase;
   }


}
```

You can implement tag specific methods in PurchaseService and PurchaseController, if Purchase owns the relationship(parent) or implement separate service and controller classes for Tag.

Comment: Thanks Firoz, this the the approach I had started to take. What is the reason for @JsonIgnore?

Comment: @JsonIgnore is to avoid cyclic references in parent child relationships and not to serialize lazily loaded properties(since invoking the getter method of lazily loaded properties outside the persistence context will result in exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

You already include a "tagging" concept in your Purchase controller: `getTagged`

I would build out a design that includes a `List<ITag> Tags` property in the Purchase model, as that might be the simplest and most straight-forward way to implement it into your current design.